# WebAPI controller not hitting without parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a route configuration that targets a particular controller with default values. The controller doesn't have any parameters for any of the action method but the action method is only being invoked when I pass an extra path i.e my controller is Calendar and action method is GetCalendarDays. I would be expecting it to invoke for `API/calendar/GetCalendarDays` but it's only invoked when I try `API/calendar/GetCalendarDays/X` I tried different combinations for route configuration but nothing really worked. I don't want to use Route attributes because I am trying to replace a current issue

I have tried multiple solutions that I found here but nothing really helps

```
    public class CalendarController : ApiController
    {
        public IEnumerable<CalendarMonth> GetCalendarMonths()
        {
            return CalendarHelper.GetCalendarMonths();
        }

        public dynamic GetCalendarDays()
        {
            return CalendarHelper.GetCalendarDays();
        }
     }


    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "defaultCalendar",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Calendar"}
            );
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                //routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Comment: So if you create a **completely new** project, and include **only those routes** and **only that controller** it doesn't work? _Please try it._

Comment: @mjwills i created a new Web API project and it worked fine when trying it there. But not working inside the project

Comment: OK, so you need to create a [mcve]. There is something else (that you haven't shown us) causing the issue. Likely a new route. Take a copy of your project. Rip bits out, piece by piece. When the bug stops - the last bit you ripped out caused your issue. Show that bit you ripped out to us, and we can explain why it is causing your issue.

Comment: Any luck on the [mcve]?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the question mark `?` in the Id that indicates that the parameter  is optional

`routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id?}"`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api#routing-by-action-name doesn't indicate it is necessary

Answer (score 0):

I've done this using this code, give it a try and let me know:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

I think that's everything you need to do. So, according to your edit, you only need to stick to your second MapHttpRoute declaration and remove the first one. Cheers.